# Solve equation when function is min

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the following function 
$$
Q=F(L,K) = min (L,K)    , L,K>0
$$

And I would like to solve the equation for K.
So as to make the graph L,K

Could you help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
K=
\begin{cases}
Q: L>Q \\
L+x:x>0,L=Q \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

If $L<Q$, the equation has no solution for $K$.